Local smart card reader / USB passthrough with RDP to VM
I have a virtual machine set up for online banking and want to pass a smart card reader that is connected to my local machine to the virtual machine. Both machines are running the latest Win 11 Pro and have appropriate drivers installed.
Initially, no redirection of any device seemed to work. After applying the suggested solution from this stackoverflow thread, I got some redirection working, namely a LED controller from my motherboard... Not even a simple usb flash drive shows up as an option for redirection, let alone the smart card reader. I've tested all redirection with USB 2 ports on the back of the motherboard to ensure compatibility (no hubs, front io, etc.) but to no avail.
Note that the virtual machine sits on an unRAID server, meaning (to my knowledge) i am forced to use RDP and can't use 3rd party software like VMWare or VirtualBox.
Are there any further steps i can take to diagnose or get it working?

Don't you need to tell unraid hypervisor to redirect local/physical host USB port to VM? Then you have to tell RDP to redirect USB like others have suggested, both need to be done

RDP "Local Resources", "Local devices and resources", "More...", lists Smart cards or Windows Hello for Business" to allow access to a smartcard on the local machine from the remote machine. This is done at the PC/SC level not at the USB level. I have not tried this from a local Windows to a remote virtual machine,
But if you can RDP to the remote virtual machine you should be able to use the smartcard.
On remote run in a cmd window "certutil -v -scinfo" to see the smartcard.

The command does actually show the smart card reader is there, my assumption stemmed from it not being in the device manager. Good stuff!
